# How to get IDataErrorInfo to propagate error messages from class to the UI?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, idataerrorinfo

I'm using VB.NET 2012
the project type is (Windows Form Application) not a (WPF Application)

The From's load event creates a Data Binding between a TextBox and the "Age" property in Class1

```
Public Class Form1
Private _Class1 As New Class1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _Class1, "Age", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    End Sub
End Class
```

As the Text property of TextBox1 changes, so does the 'Age' Property in Class1 below, the Age Property stays synchronized with what is displayed in the UI via `INotifyPropertyChanged`, if something else changes the Age property, for example the `SetVal` procedure at the bottom of Class1, the change is propagated back to the UI

The problem I’m having is getting the `IDataErrorInfo` to work in a similar way where ***errors can be propagated back to the UI***, preferably like an ErrorProvider where a little red dot is at the right of TextBox1?  Cannot find a VB example that that is clear on this. Can anyone help?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Class1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private m_age As Integer
    Public Property Age() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_age
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_age = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Age")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property [Error]() As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Error
        Get
            Return ""
        End Get
    End Property
    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal name As String) As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Item
        Get
            Dim result As String = Nothing
            If name = "Age" Then
                If Me.m_age < 0 OrElse Me.m_age > 150 Then
                    result = "Age must not be less than 0 or greater than 150."
                    ' NOTE: Flow arrives here but nothing happens, nothing is sent back to the form, 
                    ' I want this to trigger the displaying of an ErrorProvider, next to TextBox1 in the UI
                    Debug.WriteLine(m_age.ToString)
                End If
            End If
            Return result
        End Get
    End Property


    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(Name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name))
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetVal()
        Age = 0  ' NOTE: this works, the value is propagated back to the form's TextBox1
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker shared this with me.   All I was missing was an Error Provider with it's DataSource set = to _Class1. . .  Now the error conditions dynamically propagate back the Text control without any extra code

```
Public Class Form1

Private _Class1 As New Class1
Private errorProv As New ErrorProvider ' ** Here

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _Class1, "Age", False,     DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
        errorProv.ContainerControl = Me ' ** Here
        errorProv.DataSource = _Class1  ' ** and Here
    End Sub
End Class
```